# Do gravitational time dilation and SR time dilation always cancel eachother out - on every planet?

Tags: special-relativity

In the show Gravity and Me, he discusses that on Earth the bulge at the equator leads to the SR time dilation (from moving faster) to exactly equal the gravitational time dilation (from increased gravity at the poles), from the poles to the equator.  Is this true on every planet?  It seems like a very big coincidence that the speed of time is exactly equal at every place on Earth at sea level regardless of how fast the clock is moving, from the poles where a clock is not moving at all, to the equator where the clock is moving at a thousand miles an hour.

Comment: Is this a television show? A youtube video of a lecture? Who is "he?" Please give some links and information.

Comment: A BBC tv show:  https://www.bbc.co.uk/mediacentre/proginfo/2017/13/gravity-and-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a coincidence. The earth's surface is an equipotential, and the time-time component of the metric depends only on the potential.

Comment: Is this true on every planet?

Comment: @foolishmuse: Yes, it's pretty much the definition of  a planet that it's big enough so that its surface coincides with its equipotential.

Comment: Thanks.  Here is a good video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOQl8DRzQks